# One-word alternative for "double-check"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

From the given paragraph:

> I frequently forget to lock the main door. But, I know I double-checked if the door was locked today.
>
> (more texts...)
>
> I realized I became very anxious about my ***_*__*_*** about the locks on the main door.

Do we have one word to fill in the blank of the above?

Comment: FWIW (especially with J Lawler around) _double-check_ ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/double-check ) IS ONE WORD. ( http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090107171824AALJFft : Jim in Melbourne knows that he is right.) (What he thinks about the alternative open compound _double check_ ( http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double_check ) is another matter.)

Comment: As Edwin pointed out, "double-check" *is* one word. If you are looking for a synonym, that's precisely what the job of a thesaurus is. The word is also in every dictionary I checked, complete with synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Verification* would work here, but personally I'd rewrite the second sentence.

> I became very anxious about my *verification of* the locks on the main door.

This is technically correct but seems awkward somehow.

Consider:

> I became very anxious about whether the main door was locked.

Or:

> I became very anxious about whether I had, in fact, locked the main door.

[Possibly better - use of active voice not passive voice](http://www.plainlanguage.gov/howto/quickreference/dash/dashactive.cfm)

After all, are you worried about the double-check/verification, or about the door not being locked?

Answer (score 1):

what about the simple word.

> Confirm or determine

So like,

> I frequently forget to lock the main door. But, today I confirmed that the door was locked.
>
> I frequently forget to lock the main door. But, today I determined that the door was locked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we do have one word for it.

> I realized I became very anxious about my ***double-checking*** about
>   the locks on the main door.